# How to force user to save changes in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs

I have several tabs for user to fill in. Each tab has a save button and this button save  data specific to the current tab.
I used ReactJS, Redux to create the site, if it is relevant. The question is how to make sure (force) that the users click on save button before they switch to another tab?

Comment: Disable the tabs on right till the Save is clicked?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: On the HTML side you can **
$(window).blur(function() {** & force the user to save before changing tab

Comment: @Boy With Silver Wings, this means that I have to disable tabs as well as all the navigations. As the user may navigate away from the page.

Comment: @Rajaji I would like to make sure when something has changed in the data.

Answer (score 1):

Try Link and Prompt with `react-router-dom` assuming you are using that:

```
import React from 'react'
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Route,
  Link,
  Prompt
} from 'react-router-dom'

const Index = () => (
  <Router>
    <div>
      <ul>
        <li><Link to="/">Form</Link></li>
        <li><Link to="/one">One</Link></li>
        <li><Link to="/two">Two</Link></li>
      </ul>
      <Route path="/" exact component={Form} />
      <Route path="/one" render={() => <h3>One</h3>} />
      <Route path="/two" render={() => <h3>Two</h3>} />
    </div>
  </Router>
)

class Form extends React.Component {
  state = {
    isBlocking: false
  }

  render() {
    const { isBlocking } = this.state

    return (
      <form
        style={{ marginTop: '100px' }}
        onSubmit={event => {
          event.preventDefault()
          event.target.reset()
          this.setState({
            isBlocking: false
          })
        }}
      >
        <Prompt
          when={isBlocking}
          message={location => (
            `Are you sure you want to go to ${location.pathname}`
          )}
        />

        <p>
          Blocking? {isBlocking ? 'Yes, click a link or the back button' : 'Nope'}
        </p>

        <p>
          <input
            size="50"
            placeholder="type something to block transitions"
            onChange={event => {
              this.setState({
                isBlocking: event.target.value.length > 0
              })
            }}
          />
        </p>

        <p>
          <button>Submit to stop blocking</button>
        </p>

        <Link to="/">CLICK HERE TO NAVIGATE</Link>
      </form>
    )
  }
}

export default Index
```

I just tried running this code, and it worked in an existing project.

See: https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/preventing-transitions

This will hook to your router and detect navigation change and throw the message via `<Prompt />` if it detects navigating away.

Comment: 1). I have validations on a number of fields, constant saves may not be a good solution from the UX point of view. The user will be getting a number of validation errors when he does something. 2) I don't like constant saving to localstorage or to the database, this is not good from the performance point of view.

Comment: Second one didn't look bad and really the basic isBlocking state change when a user edits anything was what I was looking for! Just needed confirmation that was a good way! thanks!